# Need help in Integrating the SponsorPay/Fyber Interstitial Ads

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa, fyber

When integrating SponsorPay/Fyber Interstitial Ads, how can I check when the ad is available?
They provided this sample code:

```html
- (void)interstitialClient:(SPInterstitialClient *)client
       canShowInterstitial:(BOOL)canShowInterstitial
{
    // Assuming that this is a subclass of UIViewController
    // and that we want to show an interstitial immediately
    if (canShowInterstitial) {
        [client showInterstitialFromViewController:self];
    } else {
        // maybe try later
    }
}
```

But `canShowInterstitial` returns always `NO`, so I need to call `checkInterstitialAvailable` again and again until the ad is cached successfully.. I think this is troublesome, also many ads could be cached finally leading memory issue.. any better ways?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code snippet. This is currently the proper way of showing interstitials ad as you can see in the [documentation](http://developer.fyber.com/content/ios/interstitials/request-display-interstitial/)

Fyber's Interstitial Ads currently only work with mediation, that is with ad networks so the problem might come from the network(s) you are integrating.

There should also be no memory issues since all the data that is cached and that is not used before a new ad is received is discarded precisely to prevent that kind of problem